# Differences in Applescript functions between different system versions

Tags: applescript

My Applescript code outputs different results under different operating system versions.
Under the system of 10.13.6
[10.13.6 Image order changed!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSNNT.png)

Under the system of 10.11.6
[10.11.6 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oxwki.jpg)

The order of 10.13.6 has changed, this is definitely a disaster, because I need to rename it according to his order.I want to know what caused this order change.please kindly advise.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is a faulty assumption on your part. macOS file system APIs do not, and never have, guaranteed to return file names in a particular order. Even experienced Mac developers [make this mistake](https://indiestack.com/2017/09/unordered-directory-contents/). The old HFS+ file system may have ordered directory contents alphabetically, but APFS leaves it up to the client software. Either use an app that returns file names in sorted order, use a sorting routine to sort them yourself, or rework your script so it can process file names in any order.

Comment: Thks you,Foo,Does Mac OS AppleScript use a sorting rule when using the List Folder command?  the list folder command I wrote on 10.11.6 has been running for a year. The order in which the file names are output is the same as that seen when opened in the Finder, but the order below the 10.13.6 system is not.

Comment: Apparently not. BTW, `list folder` isn’t part of AppleScript itself; it’s defined by the Standard Additions scripting addition and has been deprecated for some time. Best solution I think would be to use Shane Stanley’s [FileManagerLib](https://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/Script_Libs.html#FileManagerLib) which provides commands for listing directories and sorting the results.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `list folder` at all.

`System Events` or `Finder` sort the files properly

```
tell application "System Events"
    name of disk items of folder "Macintosh HD:Path:to:my:folder:"
end tell
```

Comment: thanks for you help! vadian,I tried your code, but the order of the out(on 10.13.6) is also random, will this be related to the version of ScriptEditor?pls kindly advise

Comment: Also when using the Finder (Replace `System Events` with `Finder` and delete `disk`)? That's rather impossible. Do you use a custom sort order?

Comment: I don't know how to use custom sort by applescript code,I just want to rename file of the target folder. first, I have prepared a name list who named list one. second, I get the file name  list  2 of target folder. third,I use the data in list one to use the loop to modify the data in list two. but this problem is happened ,if the code running on the 10.11.6,the result is right,if the code running on the 10.13.6,the result is error. at 10.11.6, there may be potential risks, which is exactly what I am worried about. pls kindly advise